# Scythe blade warped while peening

Tags: metal, lawn-mower, sheet-metal

I warped my blade while peening it.

Several reasons could be the cause :

- it was my first time peening a scythe
- that scythe had never been peened, while used for decades, thus a lot of peening was required
- it had many dents, though not huge, and I tried to fix one until it disappeared
- I pounded on the center of the blade at some point

After doing some reading, it seems the most likely cause is that I pounded on the center of the blade, not only on the edge. I had seen that the edge was curling back on itself too much and wanted to straighten it. I thus pounded with the flat of the hammer, a bit everywhere, including in the middle of the blade. I think the warping appeared right after that.

Here are some pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Do you guys think I might be able to straighten it?

Or is it that the cause of the warping might be that the metal was spread out too much, and thus won't be able to flatten?

Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement.

Comment: @RMDman then I am guessing you'll want to close that one too? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7304/how-to-sharpen-a-lawn-mower-blade

Comment: And that one? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47114/is-my-lawnmower-beyond-redemption?rq=1

Comment: And that one? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90272/how-do-lawnmower-blade-sizes-work?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You've ruined that blade. Barring a skilled blacksmith being accessible; buy a new one, and buy a peening jig while you are at it, rather than peening freehand with zero experience.

If the blade had been used for decades without peening, trying to fix it all in one huge session was an obvious mistake. Especially freehand and your first time.